# How to force chrome to display exact size favicon (16x16) on tab?

Tags: google-chrome, favicon, autoresize

I set multi icons config on my web page, but chrome doesn't display the 16x16 file on tab, but 32x32 displayed in 16x16 instead.
Why ? is it a way to force it to display the 16x16 one ?
32x32 displayed in 16x16 is blur...

Here is my code :

```
           <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/relativepath/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
            <link rel="icon" sizes="16x16" href="/relativepath/favicon.png" type="image/png">
            <link rel="icon" sizes="32x32" href="/relativepath/favicon-32.png" type="image/png">
            <link rel="icon" sizes="64x64" href="/relativepath/favicon-64.png" type="image/png">
            <link rel="icon" sizes="96x96" href="/relativepath/favicon-96.png" type="image/png">
            <link rel="icon" sizes="196x196" href="/relativepath/favicon-196.png" type="image/png">
            <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="/relativepath/apple-touch-icon.png">
            <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="relativepath/apple-touch-icon-60x60.png">
            <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="/relativepath/apple-touch-icon-76x76.png">
            <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="/relativepath/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png">
            <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="/relativepath/apple-touch-icon-120x120.png">
            <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="/relativepath/apple-touch-icon-144x144.png">
```

Answer (score 2):

### TL; DR

Invert your 16x16 and 32x32 PNG icons declarations (so the 32x32 becomes the first one)

### The Long Answer

Unfortunately, Chrome has two issues ([324820](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=324820) and [112941](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=112941)) related to the `sizes` attribute. In short: it does not support `sizes` and loads all icons.

Years ago, I played with favicon declarations order while implementing [RealFaviconGenerator](https://realfavicongenerator.net/). I put the smallest PNG icon last and second smallest first, in order to prevent the non-supporting browsers from using a high definition icon (at that time there was a 192x192 PNG icon for Android Chrome). As of today, when using RealFaviconGenerator, [Chrome picks the 32x32 PNG icon](https://realfavicongenerator.net/favicon_compatibility).

If you are going to test a lot of configurations, I suggest you to:

- Use a different (sub)domain name for each test. Favicon caching is just too much pain. Using a tool such as [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) can do this as a side effect: simply restart it before each new experiment. Or you can configure a wildcard on an existing domain.
- Instead of having the same image in various sizes, use different icons, as done in the [favicon compatibility test](https://realfavicongenerator.net/favicon_compatibility_test). For example, make the 16x16 icon a yellow square, while the 32x32 icon will be green. That way, you can instantly see what is used.

Comment: switching declaration order doen't work. :/     It seems it always use the "real" 32x32 file, even if i switch the size properties !

Comment: Do you use a new domain when doing your tests? Else your experiments are flawed. As an alternative, you can use RealFaviconGenerator, make sure Chrome picks the 32x32 icon, and change the code progressively until you have what you want. Please report your findings!